# Change RDP settings from SSH?

Tags: ssh, rdp

Can I change permissions for a user for Windows RDP access using SSH command prompt?

Comment: Windows does not come with an SSH server.  Can you provide more details on what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I used to do it against HP machines

Answer (score 1):

if you have a windows ssh server installed, and the logged in user has administrator rights, yes you can:

```
net localgroup “Remote Desktop Users” /add username
```